# Python - Remove lines prior to current month and year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that contain arrival dates for vessels and I'd want to make python recognize the current year and month that we are at the moment and remove all entries that are prior to the current month and year.

I have a column with the date itself in the format '%d/%b/%Y' and columns for month and year separatly if needed.

For instance, if today is 01/01/2022. I'd like to remove everything that is from dec/2021 and prior.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Fernando Martins. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here are the guidelines on how to provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas [periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# set up example
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/01/2022', '08/02/2022', '09/03/2022'], 'other_col': list('ABC')})

# find dates equal or greater to this month
keep = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False)
          .dt.to_period('M')
          .ge(pd.Timestamp('today').to_period('M'))
        )

# filter
out = df[keep]
```

Output:

```
         date other_col
1  08/02/2022         B
2  09/03/2022         C
```

Comment: Hi mozway, I'm having trouble with the format of the date. They are on the format '%d/%b/%Y' (ex: 09/Aug/2022). Do you know how to adapt the code for string dates?

Comment: Nevermind the comment above.

I just converted the dates using:

`df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%b/%Y')`

Then I used your code to get the new df without the unwanted entries.

Just a follow up question: what if instead of keeping the data from the current month onward I'd wanted to *exclude* data from the current month onward?

Thanks.

Comment: @Fernando then invert the mask: `out = df[~keep]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = ...

# assuming your date column is named 'date'
t = datetime.utcnow()
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df.date) >= datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day)]
```

Comment: This kinda works. The problem is that it takes into account the day of the month as well. 

I tried with my dataframe and got the following: today is 09/Aug/2022, so the code excluded everything from 08/Aug/2022. But I need to keep the data from 01/Aug/2022 to 08/Aug/2022.

Comment: @FernandoMartins Just pass `day=1` when constructing the datetime object e.g. `datetime(t.year, t.month, day=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider this example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame()

data = [['nao victoria', '21/Feb/2012'], ['argo', '6/Jun/2022'], ['kon tiki', '23/Aug/2022']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Vessel', 'Date'])
```

You can convert your dates to datetimes, by using pandas' `to_datetime` method; for instance, you may save the output into a new Series (column):

```
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%b/%Y')
```

You end up with the following dataframe:

```
     Vessel         Date        Datetime
0   nao victoria  21/Feb/2012 2012-02-21
1           argo   6/Jun/2022 2022-06-06
2       kon tiki  23/Aug/2022 2022-08-23
```

You can then reject rows containing datetime values that are smaller than today's date, defined using datetime's `now` method:

```
df = df[df.Datetime > datetime.datetime.now()]
```

This returns:

```
     Vessel         Date   Datetime
2  kon tiki  23/Aug/2022 2022-08-23
```

Comment: Hi Sheldon, this kinda works, but I have the same problem as michotross' answer: the code takes into account the day of the month as well for the exclusions.

For insatance, today is 09/Aug/2022, so the code excluded everything from 08/Aug/2022. But I need to keep the data from 01/Aug/2022 to 08/Aug/2022. I needed it to exclude everything starting from 31/Jul/2022.